# MassTransit set headers on published message before publish filters are executed

Tags: masstransit

I would like to use MassTransit scoped publish filters to add headers to a message based on different conditions. However, I noticed that headers specified while publishing are not available in publish filters as the `PublishContext` callback is called last in the pipeline. Is there a way to pass information to filters when using `IPublishEndpoint`?

Right now, I am using a workaround by wrapping the message and publish it twice, which causes other problems. I am also thinking of introducing a scoped message context, which is populated when publishing, and can be accessed by the filter. But it would be easiest if I could somehow define that the `PublishContext` callback is executed first instead of last.

Example showing the behavior:

When publishing a message, the originator of the message adds headers to the message by using this overload.

```cs
await publishEndpoint.Publish(message, (PublishContext context) =>
{
    context.Headers.Set(MessageHeaderNames.SourceSystem, "iothub");
});
```

In the filter, I would like to access these headers, but the filter is executed before the callback, the header is not available.

```cs
public class MyPublishFilter<T> : IFilter<PublishContext<T>> where T : class
{
    public async Task Send(PublishContext<T> context, IPipe<PublishContext<T>> next)
    {
        context.Headers.TryGetHeader(MessageHeaderNames.SourceSystem, out var sourceSystem); // --> not set
    }
}
```

I'm using MassTransit v8.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pass information to the filter, you should do it via the current container scope with scoped filters. The callback is always called last, because it ultimately has the final say about how the message headers/properties are set after all other filters have been executed.